# Z-index issue with jQuery fading an element in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

so I have an interactive graphic, in which you click a div and it will display the relative information for that person. I'm using 'animate' to fade in the opacity up to 1. The problem is that when opacity reaches 1 it then jumps behind the divs you've just clicked on.

This is how one of these boards is structured..

```
<div class="boardbg board1bg">
    <div class="rollover person-1"><img src="images/hardie.png"/></div>
    <div class="rollover person-2"><img src="images/bernstein.png"/></div>
    <div class="rollover person-3"><img src="images/haldane.png"/></div>
    <div class="rollover person-4"><img src="images/cohen.png"/></div>
    <div class="rollover person-5"><img src="images/dawson.png"/></div>
    <div class="info person-1">
        <h3>hardie</h3>
        <p>blablablablabla
        </p>
        <h5>click to close</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="info person-2">
        <h3>bernstein/h3>
        <p>blablablablabla
        </p>
        <h5>click to close</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="info person-3">
        <h3>haldane</h3>
        <p>blablablablabla
        </p>
        <h5>click to close</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="info person-4">
        <h3>cohen</h3>
        <p>blablablablabla
        </p>
        <h5>click to close</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="info person-5">
        <h3>dawson</h3>
        <p>blablablablabla
        </p>
        <h5>click to close</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="backbtn">BACK</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery works like this...

```
$( ".rollover" ).click(function() {
$(".info").css('display', 'none');
person = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
$(".info."+person).css('display', 'block');
$(".info."+person).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 200);
});

$( ".info" ).click(function() {
person = $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
$(".info."+person).animate({"opacity": "0"}, 200);
$(".info."+person).css('display', 'none');
});
```

I have tried to correct the problem using css z-index attributes but to no avail. Is it something to do with them all being in the same div???

You can see an example if you follow this link and select the top-left picture (Pioneers), then click any of the pictures.

http://thetally.efinancialnews.com/tallyassets/extramile/index.html

Thanks for any help, I'm stumped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.info` (=Infotext) defaults to `position: static`, but your `.rollover` (=photos) are `position: absolute` so they are always on top. Just set in your **CSS**:

```
.info {position: relative;} // now you're done
```

BTW:

- I can't explain why `.info` is on top during animation.
- `z-index` works only for elements with position other than static.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the value of the opacity to 0.99.